# Is there a way of finding the average distance of selected features in a layer

Tags: qgis

My problem is i have a layer with thousands of vectors in a layer. Using the 'select features by area' tool I have used the tool to select vectors within a 100m^2 area but I want to find the average length of the vector lines selected is there a way of finding the average of selected features in a layer

Answer (score 3):

Given the clarification that this concerns lines, here is one possible solution based on the Field calculator and Statistical summary-tools, which finds the average length of the selected lines without having to save them as a separate layer.

Before doing your selection, find the length of the lines. Open the attribute table of the line layer. Toggle editing mode on the left hand side of the attribute table toolbar and open the field calculator to the right. Type in an output field name and specify the field type which is to hold the values in the the attribute table ('len_km', set to decimal number in the figure below). Then find and double click $length under Geometry, click OK and click the editing tool again, opting to save edits. %length is divided by 1000 below to transform from meters to kilometers.

[image]

Back in the main window make your feature selection and then click the epsilon symbol to the right on the toolbar. On the bottom you can then check the box for selected features only. This then displays a range of statistics for the selected features, as in the figure below. Make sure you choose the correct column from the drop-down menu, as circled.

[image]

You could also choose to use the field calculator to 'Only update selected features' and then find the column average, or you could, as mentioned, start by saving your selected features as a separate layer and do the the above steps without having to specify 'Selected features only' for any of them.

You might also find this tutorial of use:
https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/calculating_line_lengths.html